# Create React App Uninstall Global Install Loop

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

(Windows 10) So, I tried to create a React app, and it asked me to uninstall a global installation of it by running `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` and the image below is what's returned.

[image]

Now, I try and re-run `npx create-react-app .`  inside my terminal in VS Code and it asks me to do the same thing over and over again to uninstall. I have tried restarting my vscode as well, that didn't work.

Comment: I've experienced the same on macOS the other day. I ended up doing global uninstall, and then global install to get the latest version. That got me out of this loop.

Comment: Okay that worked re-installing the create-react-app as global dependency thanks